# Problem in accessing localized string in ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, localization, multilingual

I created an ASP.NET MVC application and added 2 resource file for about.aspx page in the project. It looks like this:

[image: alt folder structure]

Then I modified the About.aspx page as following:

```
<asp:Content ID="aboutContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h2><%= GetLocalResourceObject ("About")%></h2>
    <p>
        <%= GetLocalResourceObject ("PutContentHere")%>
    </p>
</asp:Content>
```

I tried to run the about page after [changing the firefox locale](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/1333) to hi-IN but it still shows the default text (in English). Please can you spot the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentculture.aspx) and [`CurrentUICulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentuiculture.aspx) does not automatically change according to what the browser reports. You will need to specify that:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = 
                          CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(Request.UserLanguages[0]);
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = 
                          System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // handle the exception
    }
    base.OnInit(e);
}
```

You should note that some of the languages that you can select ("en" for instance), will cause an exception when trying to assign it to [`Thread.CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentculture.aspx), since it does not allow what is called "neutral" cultures. In short, a neutral culture is one that identifies only a language, but not geographical region. You can read more about that in [the documentation for the `CultureInfo` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx).

Comment: I have few resource string in my master page as well. Do I have to define all those strings in resource file of all pages?

Comment: @Hermant: you add resources for master pages in the same way, as for aspx pages. Instead of calling the resource file pagefilename.aspx.resx you call it masterfilename.master.resx.