# Multilingual website

Tags: asp.net-2.0, multilingual

I would like to have home page of my website in the language of client. Because site is hosted at one location but it can be access through any n number of country. So i want to have home page in the language of requested client browser.

There is also one important point, i.e. suppose if client language is not supported at server then site should be visible in fallback language.

Does you have any example site/ good link ?

Answer (score 5):

This is not really an answer to the question as much as a general advice...If you decide to send the output to the user in the language you consider best for him/her based on GeoIP, browser language etc. make sure it is VERY simple to find the language selection control on the site at all times even if you don't know the language.

There is nothing more annoying than being presented with a site in Hungarian just because you happen to be in the hotel lobby using a computer where you don't have access to the browser settings (unless you speak the language).

Also, despite being a Swede and having Swedish as my first language I almost always prefer an English or German site in English or German in front of a translated one. Important things get lost in translation way too often and as long as the language is not stopping me I know what I prefer. I realize that this is not the "normal situation" for most of your users but please keep us in mind :)

Comment: Excellent point (Can I +100?)! This may not be the exact answer to the question but i think it is even more important than the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer posted to [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147028/problem-in-accessing-localized-string-in-asp-net-mvc-application) answers this one too!

Answer (score 0):

You could look at [.NET Internationalization](http://www.dotneti18n.com/) which is the website for the book of the same name. There is [a review of it](http://www.craigmurphy.com/blog/?p=623) on [Craig Murphy's blog](http://www.craigmurphy.com/blog/).

Answer (score 0):

For the Multilingual Website Tutorial you can visit this below 2 links for ASP.NET Webform & ASP.NET MVC4.

http://dotnetawesome.blogspot.com/2014/09/how-to-create-multilingual-website-in-aspnet-mvc4.html

http://dotnetawesome.blogspot.com/2014/06/how-to-create-multilingual-application-aspnet.html

Answer (score 0):

This is how I am creating multilingual website. It has fallback language option also.

Code Language: [PHP](http://php.net)

Directory Structure:

```
/
|- core
|  |- init.php
|  `- lang
|     |- en_US.UTF-8.ini
|     `- hi_IN.UTF-8.ini
|
`- dashboard.php
```

Language Filename: **en_US.UTF-8.ini**

```
[Headers]
HEADER_DASHBOARD = "Dashboard";
HEADER_USERS     = "Users";
HEADER_GROUPS    = "Groups";
HEADER_HELP      = "Help";

[MainMenu]
MENU_DASHBOARD = "Dashboard";
MENU_USERS     = "Users";
MENU_GROUPS    = "Groups";
MENU_HELP      = "Help";
```

Filename: **init.php**

```
<?php
$available_lang = [
         'en' => 'en_US.UTF-8',
         'hi' => 'hi_US.UTF-8',
      ];

//check if requested language is available or fallback to default.
$language = (isset($available_lang[$_GET['ln']])) ? $available_lang[$_GET['ln']]:'en_US.UTF-8';

$_SESSION['language'] = $_GET['ln'];

$ini = parse_ini_file("/core/lang/" . $language . ".ini");
?>
```

Filename: **dashboard.php?ln=en**

```
<?php
require_once 'core/init.php';

if ($_SESSION['language']) == 'en') {
    echo '<a href="?ln=hi">Hindi</a>';
} else {
    echo '<a href="?ln=en">English</span></a>';
}

// example uses
echo $ini['HEADER_GROUPS']; // Dashboard
?>
```