# Internationalization in master pages in .NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, internationalization, master-pages

I'm doing some internationalization for first time, and I have an issue:

I would like to know if it is possible to internationalize from a master page. I added a dropdown list with some languages and I'm using a session , so when I change a language, the new Culture is detected and it changes, the page is reloaded and the contents (I'm using resources) translated. But it's not working.

Here I attach some code:

--Modules.master.vb--

```
    Protected Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
    _Website = clsWebsiteDA.GetById(CInt(Request.QueryString("web")))
    If Not Session("cms_language") Is Nothing Then
        LanguageDropDownList1.SelectedValue = Session("cms_language")
        Dim sCulture As String = Session("cms_language")
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(sCulture)
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = New CultureInfo(sCulture)
    End If
End Sub

    Protected Sub LanguageDropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles LanguageDropDownList1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Session("cms_language") = LanguageDropDownList1.SelectedValue
    Response.Redirect(Request.Url.ToString)
End Sub
```

End Class

--Modules.master(aspx)--

```
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="LanguageDropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                            Height="16px" Width="65px" 
                            meta:resourcekey="LanguageDropDownList1Resource1">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="nl" meta:resourcekey="ListItemResource1">Dutch</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="fr" meta:resourcekey="ListItemResource1">French</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="es" meta:resourcekey="ListItemResource2">Spanish</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="en" meta:resourcekey="ListItemResource3">English</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
```

If it cannot be done like this, what is the proper approach?
Thanks in advance,

Alf.

**UPDATE:**

I found through this [link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1337798.aspx) the solution that I think that fits with my problem. But now I have a problem of inheritance.
I created in the folder a new WebForm called Basepage.aspx:

```
Imports System.Globalization
```

Imports System.Threading

Partial Class Basepage
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

```
Protected Overrides Sub InitializeCulture()
    If Request.Form("DropDownList1") IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim selectedLanguage As String = _
            Request.Form("DropDownList1")
        UICulture = Request.Form("DropDownList1")
        Culture = Request.Form("DropDownList1")
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = _
            CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(selectedLanguage)
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = New  _
            CultureInfo(selectedLanguage)
    End If
    MyBase.InitializeCulture()
End Sub
```

End Class

But, when I subtitute for example, in one of my pages,

```
Partial Class Administration_index
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
```

for

```
    Partial Class Administration_index
Inherits Basepage
```

it complains saying that it's not defined. How can I deal with this inheritance?
VB appreciated,though C# is ok...

Comment: Are you using resource files?

Comment: SOLVED!!! I was messing between the Session and the dropdownlist. Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have to tried to override the initializeCulture event of the Page class?

eg:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes culture for the page
        /// </summary>
        [VersionChange( "6.1.34.89", "24/12/2009", "Custom Cultures added" )]
        protected override void InitializeCulture()
        {
            try
            {
                CultureInfo oCultureInfo;

                try
                {
                    oCultureInfo = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture( this.CurrentCustomCulture );
                }
                catch ( ArgumentException )
                {
                    //Get culture info based on Great Britain
                    CultureInfo cultureInfo = new CultureInfo( "en-GB" );
                    RegionInfo regionInfo = new RegionInfo( cultureInfo.Name );

                    CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder cultureAndRegionInfoBuilder = new CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder( this.CurrentCustomCulture, CultureAndRegionModifiers.None );

                    cultureAndRegionInfoBuilder.LoadDataFromCultureInfo( cultureInfo );
                    cultureAndRegionInfoBuilder.LoadDataFromRegionInfo( regionInfo );

                    // Custom Changes
                    cultureAndRegionInfoBuilder.CultureEnglishName = this.CurrentCustomCulture;
                    cultureAndRegionInfoBuilder.CultureNativeName = this.CurrentCustomCulture;

                    cultureAndRegionInfoBuilder.Register();

                    oCultureInfo = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo( this.CurrentCustomCulture );
                }
                catch ( Exception )
                {
                    throw;
                }

                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = oCultureInfo;
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = oCultureInfo;

                Page.Culture = oCultureInfo.Name;
                Page.UICulture = oCultureInfo.Name;

                base.InitializeCulture();
            }
            catch ( Exception )
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

EDIT:
Added base page example

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;
using System.Web.UI;
using Objects.Database;
using Objects.Engine;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Objects.Controls
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Base class for all web pages
    /// </summary>
    [VersionChange( "6.1.38.112", "19/01/2010", "SessionKeys class now used" )]
    public class BasePage : Controls.TabPersistentWebPage
    {
        //- PROPERTIES --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        #region Properties

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or Sets the Custom Culture for the system
        /// </summary>
        [VersionChange( "6.1.34.89", "24/12/2009", "Custom Cultures added" )]
        protected string CurrentCustomCulture
        {
            get
            {
                if ( Session[ SessionKeys.CurrentCustomCulture ] == null )
                {
                    //Set the culture to the system default
                    Session[ SessionKeys.CurrentCustomCulture ] = Settings.Instance.SystemCulture;
                }

                return Session[ SessionKeys.CurrentCustomCulture ].ToString();
            }
            set
            {
                Session[ SessionKeys.CurrentCustomCulture ] = value;
            }
        }

        #endregion Properties

        //- EVENTS ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        #region Events

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes culture for the page
        /// </summary>
        [VersionChange( "6.1.34.89", "24/12/2009", "Custom Cultures added" )]
        protected override void InitializeCulture()
        {
            try
            {
                CultureInfo oCultureInfo;

                try
                {
                    oCultureInfo = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture( this.CurrentCustomCulture );
                }
                catch ( ArgumentException )
                {
                    //Get culture info based on Great Britain
                    CultureInfo cultureInfo = new CultureInfo( "en-GB" );
                    RegionInfo regionInfo = new RegionInfo( cultureInfo.Name );

                    CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder cultureAndRegionInfoBuilder = new CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder( this.CurrentCustomCulture, CultureAndRegionModifiers.None );

                    cultureAndRegionInfoBuilder.LoadDataFromCultureInfo( cultureInfo );
                    cultureAndRegionInfoBuilder.LoadDataFromRegionInfo( regionInfo );

                    // Custom Changes
                    cultureAndRegionInfoBuilder.CultureEnglishName = this.CurrentCustomCulture;
                    cultureAndRegionInfoBuilder.CultureNativeName = this.CurrentCustomCulture;

                    cultureAndRegionInfoBuilder.Register();

                    oCultureInfo = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo( this.CurrentCustomCulture );
                }
                catch ( Exception )
                {
                    throw;
                }

                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = oCultureInfo;
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = oCultureInfo;

                Page.Culture = oCultureInfo.Name;
                Page.UICulture = oCultureInfo.Name;

                base.InitializeCulture();
            }
            catch ( Exception )
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Pre Render
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e">args</param>
        [VersionChange("6.2.58.180", "23/06/2010", "IE7 Compatibility mode forced")]
        protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                //Force IE7 compatibility
                Page.Header.Controls.AddAt(0, new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlMeta() { HttpEquiv = "X-UA-Compatible", Content = "IE=EmulateIE7" }); 

                base.OnPreRender(e);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        #endregion Events

        //- METHODS -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        #region Methods

        /// <summary>
        /// Formats a decimal number to the specified format in the settings
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="d">Decimal</param>
        /// <returns>string representation of the decimal</returns>
        protected string FormatDecimal( decimal d )
        {
            try
            {
                return d.ToString( Settings.Instance.DecimalFormat );
            }
            catch ( Exception )
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Removes a menu item based on the value
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="MenuItemValue">The value of the menu item</param>
        /// <param name="Menu">The Menu with the item to remove</param>
        [VersionChange( "6.1.36.102", "11/01/2010", "Added this method to remove menu items. Duplicate from MasterBasePage", "AF" )]
        protected void RemoveMenuItem( string MenuItemValue, Menu Menu )
        {
            try
            {
                foreach ( MenuItem oMenuItem in Menu.Items )
                {
                    if ( oMenuItem.Value == MenuItemValue )
                    {
                        //Menu.Items.Remove( oMenuItem );
                        oMenuItem.Enabled = false;
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch ( Exception )
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Opens a help window
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="Link">The link to open</param>
        [VersionChange( "6.1.41.125", "08/02/2010", "Method added to open a help window" )]
        protected void OpenHelp( string Link )
        {
            try
            {
                base.OpenWindow( Link, 800, 600, "Help", Enums.ScrollBars.Two, true, true, false, false );
            }
            catch ( Exception )
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        #endregion

        //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    }
}
```

Comment: I will try the override! BTW,I read in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureandregioninfobuilder.aspx , "The application should use the CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder class to create a custom culture that is new or overrides a predefined culture, and to install the custom culture on a computer", but I just want to use one of the existing, not to create I new one.I guess I just have to use CultureInfo class to take dates,currency... right?Thank u very much!

Comment: Hi alfizqu - I have read your updated post, I see you are having a problem with the base page. have you added a 'using' statement for the namespace the base page is in. In my base pages I only have the cs file and no aspx file. I have attached my base page as an example.

Comment: Additionally, note the Base Page inheriets from another base page ( in another assembly in this case ) You just need to change your code behind to inheriet from your new base page, I would recomend making a class rather than an aspx page to inheriet from. N

Comment: OK, I created a class instead but actually nothing changed... About the using statement, I searched for information but I just understood that it works like a Try..Catch, but I don't get the use. The Basepage doesn't appear as a namespace, but I don't know how to fix it,so it would appear (I think that if it appeared, it would work, right?).On the other hand, I placed the BasePage.vb in Administration/modules,but maybe I should place it in App_Code...What do u think?  Thank you for helping!

Comment: Hi, If you look in the code for my base page the 'using' statements are at the top. Sorry there are two using keyworks in c#. it might be called Imports in VB. The namespace is just below this. In my example its Objects.Controls. So my page would inheriet from Objects.Controls.BasePage.   eg:  your page would be like this:  public class YourPage : Objects.Controls.BasePage.

Comment: I managed to solve the inheritance problem, the file was not well located as I expected, the are no errors anymore, but still with the overriding is not working. I'll try to find out what's happening, thank you for your help! I learned a lot from it.

Comment: So, here I am again. I solved this but debugging I found out that in the override InitializeCulture() (the code is in my update) it's not happening that ""If Request.Form("LanguageDropDownList1") IsNot Nothing Then"", so it's not recognizing the dropdownlist or something... how can it be possible?  My dropdownlist is set-up! I took the Request.Form() from an example of msdn...

Comment: I think initialize culter is called in the page life cycle before all the controls are set up and the viewstate etc loaded. I would store the required culture in the session as in my example, you can then load the culture from there rather than directly from the drop down and set the session variable when the drop down is changed.

Comment: @alfizqu - ps, please mark as answer if this has solved your problem. It will make it easier for someone else to find if they have a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

A similar question (specifically about localized string resources) was asked and answered elsewhere: [Localizing strings in master pages of ASP.NET MVC application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147367/localizing-strings-in-master-pages-of-asp-net-mvc-application)

The key point, as you noted, is that a `MasterPage` isn't a type of `Page` so it doesn't have access to the Page's resource mechanisms.

If what you need to do is localize strings in a master page, and if the localized strings can be found in a global resource file, this code will work in your master page's codebehind:

```
protected string GetLocalizedString(string key)
{
    return (string) GetGlobalResourceObject("default.aspx", key);
}
```

You can reference that localized string with code like this in the master page itself:

```
<h1><%= GetLocalizedString("header_string_identifier") %></h1>
```

This all depends on the resource file `default.aspx.resx` being in your `App_GlobalResources` directory. Although you obviously know how to create a resource file, for completeness I'll say that the easiest way to do so is by invoking Add, then Add New Item, then Resource File from the project's context menu in Visual Studio.

Although it's easy to create a resource entry using the resource editor built into Visual Studio, you can also edit it manually. Either way, the resource file should contain a section like this:

```
  <data name="header_string_identifier" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>This is the H1 text to display.</value>
  </data>
```

The two details not to miss are:

- Make sure that the `name=` in the resource entry matches the key
  parameter in the master page directive.
- Make sure that the first
  parameter in the `GetGlobalResourceObject` call matches the name of
  the resource file with the trailing `.resx` removed.